# How to use Jquery webcam for mobile devices (Android,iphone)?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, webcam

I'm developing a mobile web applications using jquery mobile, HTML 5.
From this application I want to access the camera. For that I'm using this plugin
http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

It is working fine in desktop browsers but it is not working in mobile devices (Android, iPhone).

I think the problem is using swf in that plugin. It might not be supported for mobile devices.

Please suggest any other options instead of .swf file

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083617/accessing-webcam-with-javascript . What you ask is currently not possible without native mobile code or flash.

Comment: is that possible using jquery mobile?otherwise any other option is there please suggest me.

Comment: Nope. Device access is an HTML5 thing, more than just jQuery. You will need to either wait until mobile browsers support HTML5 more fully, or build an actual phone app for the relevant platform.

Comment: ok will this plugin http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ work in mobile devices?

Comment: No. You can't do what you want to do without building an Android or iOS app at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access from the Browser to Camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387978/access-from-the-browser-to-camera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check out this 
[Access from the Browser to Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387978/access-from-the-browser-to-camera/10136104#10136104)

This will be currently supporting opera mobile in android.