# Camera control HTML/PHP/Javascript for Smartphones?

Tags: android, ios, html, ios4, smartphone

Can I access the camera of an iOS or Android smartphone using HTML5, Javascript, or PHP so the users can take pictures and view it after it has been taken?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access from the Browser to Camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387978/access-from-the-browser-to-camera)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `camera` API with Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Camera_API

Comment: I cannot get the img#show-picture URL to update... which means the JS is failing... even though its loaded. Any thoughts? I have reapplied the code exactly, but also tried tweaking elements to ensure the connections were valid. No go! :0

Comment: I forgot to load jQuery with the example above! That fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use this html5 code cause it work for me.

```
  <input type="file" class='form-control' accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.