# Loop over setTimeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have a problem to 'continuously refresh' the picture which is captured from my camera every 1 second. Right now the picture only changes to the last picture taken by the camera.
Any ideas how to make this work????

```
    function reflashIPCam(){
        newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = "image taken from the camera" + new Date().getTime();
        document.getElementById("IPCamIMG").src = newImage.src;
    }

    function playIPCamLoop(){
        for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
            delayFunction();
        }
    }

    function delayFunction(){
        setTimeout(reflashIPCam, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the timing, I would think the simplest way to recur is with a setInterval

```
intervalRef = setInterval(reflashIPCam, 1000);
```

and if you want to stop it after 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout("clearInterval(intervalRef)", 5000);
```

For getting data from the camera, please see [access-from-the-browser-to-camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387978/access-from-the-browser-to-camera)

Comment: thanks! just with a little modification of your code, mine works perfectly nice! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
delayFunction() {
     setTimeout(reflashIPCam, 1000);
}
```

you program the call of the `reflashIPCam` function 1000 ms from the time of execution of `delayFunction`.

As the loop is instantaneous, that means you program all calls for the same time. So of course you can only see the last execution.

You can fix it like this :

```
function playIPCamLoop(){
    for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
        delayFunction(i+1);
    }
}

function delayFunction(i){
    setTimeout(reflashIPCam, i*1000);
}
```

Comment: Hi dystroy, I just tried your code, the problem is still there. It only shows the last picture taken. The picture is same as the startup one during the mean time