# Android webview input photo button doesn't work

Tags: java, android, input, webview

I'm working in an Android Webview project and I need to access my device photos and videos, but my buttons doesn't work and I don't receive any error message.

This is my HTML code below:

```
<strong>Send Photo</strong>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="capture" capture="camera" name="txFile">
<br>            
<strong>Send Video</strong>
<input type="file" accept="video/*" id="capture" capture="camcorder" name="txFile2">
```

This is my Java code:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
myWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this,"Exemplo");
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}
```

[This is how to show in Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWNbY.png)

I appreciate every help on this!

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong

Comment: I tried to use Nexus 4 (Android 4.4 - kitkat) and I received this console message: "Using the 'capture' attribute as an enum is deprecated. Please use it as a boolean and specify the media types that should be accepted in the 'accept' attribute.", source:  (0) @AntonMalyshev

Comment: So.. Did you try capture="true"?

Comment: May I have to change my html to <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="capture" capture="true" name="txFile"> ? Sorry @AntonMalyshev could you tell me where do I try capture="true"?

Comment: Yes, I meant this. But it could be no luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646366/open-camera-in-android-webview-using-html-js

Comment: No deal... Maybe the error is on Java code! I don't know why it's happen... By browser is ok, only doesn't work on Android browser... @AntonMalyshev

Comment: anyone else could help me?